# How to create a Lead with a custom record type?

Tags: apex, record-type, developer-console, custom, insert

I'm trying to test a workflow rule made, and I'm trying to insert some Leads, with determined Recordtypes to cover all test scenarios.

In Dev Console/IDE, how to create a Lead with a custom Record type?

Is it possible to create with the RT Name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Developer Console you can do the following

```
Lead l = new Lead(Company = 'foo', LastName = 'bar',
                  RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType
                                    WHERE DeveloperName = 'My_Record_Type' AND
                                          SObjectType = 'Lead'][0].Id);
insert l;
```

That is, you have to set the value of an ID  Lead.RecordTypeId field but you can locate it via SOQL.

Or, you can do without the query using the Schema Describe methods ...

```
Lead l = new Lead(Company = 'foo', LastName = 'bar',
                  RecordTypeId = :Lead.SobjectType.getDescribe()
                                   .getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()
                                   .get('My_Record_Type').getRecordTypeId());

insert l;
```